# 'skippable-exception-classes' is not permitted on the step

Tags: java, spring, jboss, spring-batch

I had a spring-batch application which has a parent step which has a parent step like below:

```
<step id="baseStep" abstract="true"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk>
            <skippable-exception-classes>
                <include class="java.lang.NullPointerException"/>
                <include class="java.lang.NumberFormatException"/>              
            </skippable-exception-classes>
        </chunk>
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="commonStepListener" />
        </listeners>
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

I have a child class which inherits the parent class like below:

```
<step id="callDataFromStore" parent="baseStep"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="myTableReader" processor="myTableProcessor"
            writer="myWebServiceWriter" commit-interval="10">
        </chunk>
        <listeners merge="true">
            <listener ref="myItemSkipListener" />
        </listeners>
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

Not that I have not specified skip-limit in either parent or child steps. I'm using spring batch 3.0.8. While executing, I'm encountered with the following exception

```
: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'callDataFromStagingTable.masterStep': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'callDataFromStore' while setting bean property 'step'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'callDataFromStore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The field 'skippable-exception-classes' is not permitted on the step [callDataFromStore] because there is no 'skip-limit'.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.WSComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(WSComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:56)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:137)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.performInvocation(JBossWSInvoker.java:169)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:145)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:252)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'callDataFromStore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The field 'skippable-exception-classes' is not permitted on the step [callDataFromStore] because there is no 'skip-limit'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 91 more

The issue I'm facing here is that mine is an upgrade application. I'm upgrading from spring batch 2.1.8 to 3.0.8.  Also, the old application was using weblogic and I have changed it to jboss. This exception was not occuring while executing the job in spring batch version 2.1.8.
Any leads on what could be the possible issue? Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

The exception is pretty clear.  It says that you can't configure skippable exceptions without also specifying a skip limit which your configuration does not have.  Add a skip limit and you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks. That resolves my issue. But I want to know what has changed in higher versions which is causing this issue. I checked the spring-batch-core implementation class and the validation seems to be there in older and higher versions. So just wanted to know whats the cause and is there any solution other than adding skip-limit

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core/2.1.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/xml/StepParserStepFactoryBean.java?av=f
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core/3.0.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/xml/StepParserStepFactoryBean.java/